# Join two tables with left-hand side arbitrary date to right-hand side month end date

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I left outer join on a date that is listed as a daily date like (9/13/2016) to a another date in another table listed as a month end date like (30-SEP-16)?

table one - transaction date:'9/13/2016'
table two - monthly date:  '30-SEP-16'

Comment: 30-SEP-16 is not end of month date.
Do you want to join when month and year are equal or you want to do something specific with last day of month?

Comment: @Kacper . . . 2016-09-30 *is* the end of the month on calendars that I'm familiar with.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You're absolutely right I've seen SEP but read AUG. But still I don't understand join condition.

Comment: Your example dates suggest that dates are stored in textual representation and different formats? Is that the problem, or are you getting difficulty in joining each date with the corresponding end of month date? And any preference on sql vendor?(oracle, tsql, mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trunc()`.  Here is one method:

```
select . . .
from t1 join
     t2 
     on trunc(t1.transactiondate, 'MON') = trunc(t2.monthlydate, 'MON');
```

This transforms both dates to the beginning of the month.

In some databases, I would caution against using functions on both sides of the join condition.  Such functions can preclude the use of indexes.  In Oracle, however, you can easily define an index on an expression, making it more efficient.

You can also write the condition as:

```
select . . .
from t1 join
     t2 
     on t1.transactiondate >= trunc(t2.monthlydate, 'MON') AND
        t1.transactiondate < t2.monthlydate + 1;
```

(If you know that `transactiondate` has no time component, you can use `t1.transactiondate <= t2.monthlydate`.)

If the dates are actually stored as strings, then you can use `to_date()` to convert them to dates and follow the logic in the above queries.

Answer (score 0):

If the date is always the last day of the month, you can use the `last_day()` function just on the left side:

```
... where last_day(t1.transaction_date) = t2.monthly_date
```

However, this only works if `monthy_date` is a "pure" date (with the time set to 00:00:00).